# How do I quickly transfer a large archive (~16GB)

Tags: download, cluster, parallelism

How do I quickly transfer a large archive (~16GB) from one mount point to another on 80 servers? The mount points are on separate partitions. I tried ansible (with the -f 100 option) and a bash script with rsync in a loop, but both methods are very slow, and neither seems elegant.

Comment: This question is unclear as it stands now. What are you trying to do? Copying or moving a directory tree? Via SSH? Where is your bottleneck? Are you doing all transfers sequentially or in parallel?

Comment: I am trying to _copy_ a large directory tree from one folder to another one localy. I need to do _in parallel_ on ~80 hosts. And there is a bottleneck in a script which I launch on the deployment machine, and it uses ssh and ansible to launch the copy process on the remote servers.

Comment: So if you run 80 invocations of `cp` in parallel, each copying the directory structure on the individual hosts, where's the *slow* part? Are you IO bound by the disks of the individual hosts? I don't know where your bottleneck is. It's apparently not the network because it's a local copy on each host. If local copy is slow, then maybe you're dealing with a lot of small files. In that case see [Speed up copying 1000000 small files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124527/12779).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd install [pdsh](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/pdsh.html) and configure it to allow me to run commands in parallel on all servers (or selected individual hosts or groups of servers - as defined in `pdsh`'s [/etc/genders](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/genders.html) file).

e.g. after installing `pdsh`, configuring it to use ssh (rather than the odd default of rsh) and defining an `all` group that contains all servers:

```sh
pdsh -g all mv /old /new |& tee /tmp/pdsh.log
```

You can view the log file with less (etc), or nicely formatted with one section per host with `pdsh`'s `dshbak` utility:

```sh
dshback /tmp/pdsh.log
```

Each output line is prefixed with the hostname it came from (which is what `dshbak` uses to group output by hostname):

```sh
# pdsh -g all uptime
hanuman:  22:24:53 up 60 days,  1:38,  8 users,  load average: 0.05, 0.03, 0.05
indra:  22:24:16 up 14 days, 25 min,  3 users,  load average: 0.22, 0.40, 0.44
ganesh:  22:24:53 up 49 days,  7:56,  6 users,  load average: 0.73, 0.79, 0.79
kali:  22:25:05 up 3 min,  0 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.03, 0.02
```

`pdsh` also includes a useful `pdcp` command to copy a file to many servers in parallel.  e.g. to copy `/etc/genders` from the local host to all servers:

```
pdcp -g all /etc/genders /etc/
```

`pdsh` was originally designed for use on HPC clusters, but is equally as useful on any groups(s) of servers, including web-server farms, replicating database servers, etc.  The ability to assign an arbitrary label to any group of servers is useful here, e.g. label some groups of machines as `web`, `mysql`, `dns`, and also have them in `all`.

There are several other cluster ssh tools around but in my experience, `pdsh` is the simplest to use and easiest to configure.

Puppet, Ansible etc are great for mass-deployment and updates, and pdsh is great for mass command-line server administration.

Answer (score 1):

Consider trying multicast or broadcast the files on the lan and receiving it on all clients from the same stream. It will then take the time for ONE copy...

See for instance:

```
http://linux.die.net/man/1/udp-sender
```

Good luck,
gerhard