# Rsync copying everything again, not deltas

Tags: debian, rsync, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to sync two mounted volumes (1TB) in a single machine with rsync. Perhaps this might not be the best approach, but I'm trying to figure out what could be wrong, as on every launch, rsync copies everything again, not just the differences.

The exact command is:

```
find . -type f|parallel -v -j 24 rsync -ar --progress /dbdata/{} /dbdata2/{}
```

As I'm trying to achieve maximum copy speed via parallelizing the process.

PS: dirs/folders previously created by find|mkdir

Debian Jessie

What else should I provide for you? Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post the exact command you're using?

Comment: @clk command added, thanks for commenting

Comment: How can running file transfers to the same location be faster done in parallel?  I think you're shooting yourself in the foot and the fact that you list each individual file probably causes `rsync` to copy them without validation.

Comment: @JuliePelletier  Parallelism was added to try to overcome the overhead of analyzing/comparing sequentially 50000 files. There's plenty of CPU power available (using around 25%) and also IOPS (using gp2 volumes in AWS). Tried the same sync without parallel and same happened, full copy on second pass, not just deltas/differences

Comment: Running it in parallel is going to thrash the disk. Get rid of the `find` and just use `rsync`. There are options to tell it to only use file size etc to determine; otherwise it needs to read both copies of the files anyway.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco tried that earlier today, but even that way it wrote everything back again. The disk still has I/O available

Comment: What kind of filesystems are they?

Comment: @JeffSchaller ext4

Comment: Does parallelization speed up copying from a single disk? Well, it depends. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124527/speed-up-copying-1000000-small-files

Answer (score 3):

By default rsync does not do delta calculations on local copies, only over the network. You can add `-no-W`    or `--no-whole-file` to override this.  `--stats` will show more info on what happened. Setting a fixed `--block-size=` value allows you to choose what size blocks should be considered.

Comment: That's the kind of answer  I was looking for, I'll try that ASAP. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Minor edit: at least in Debian the argument is '--no-whole-file'...executing and timing right now...thanks again. I'll provide feedback as soon as it finishes running.

Comment: It actually took the same time, perhaps the filesystem should have been mounted with no-atime as it is a database :)

Answer (score 2):

Parallelization is not a magic bullet that makes things faster. Parallelization requires *independent*, or at least loosely coupled, tasks. Parallelization only helps if the tasks don't compete (much) for resources.

Since rsync is I/O bound, and not CPU bound, there's not much to be gained by running multiple instances in parallel. If the copy process is limited by bandwidth, then there is no way to gain anything by parallelizing, you can only lose due to the overhead of parallelization. (Parallelization always has an overhead since the system is switching between tasks. It's only worthwhile if the gains offset the cost.)

It is possible to gain an advantage from parallelization if you can't saturate the available bandwidth due to latency, i.e. if rsync spends a significant fraction of its time waiting for a read to complete. However it is extremely unlikely that latency would be so high that you'd get some benefit from 24 parallel instances. With most disk hardware, parallel accesses have a high cost due to [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)). If you have hardware that's able to parallelize requests, then there may be some gain, but I doubt that any hardware handles 24 parallel requests. Try with two instances, but measure, don't speculate.

Regarding delta copies, that's only an optimization when the bottleneck is the bandwidth between the source and the destination. Delta copies make sense when there is a local rsync that can calculate checksums very fast, a remote rsync that can calculate checksums very fast, and a network in the middle that takes a lot more time to transmit the data than rsync takes to calculate checksums. With local files, rsync needs to read the source and the destination to calculate the checksums. If writes are roughly as fast as reads then delta copies can only hurt since the reads, at best, prevent an equal amount of writes. If writes are significantly slower than reads, then delta copies might help, but that would be somewhat unusual. You can pass `--no-whole-file` to force delta transfers, but don't be surprised if this makes the copy slower. Once again, profile, don't speculate.

Comment: Thanks for such a complete answer...unfortunately due to timing issues we had to move over and ended just cloning the whole disk for the sake of time to market, so couldn't actually test / tune the whole rsync as I wanted to :(