# Speed up existing mv process

Tags: linux, mv

I'm attempt to move a huge directory from one hard drive to another. It has around six TB worth of small files (4kb-100kb mostly).

It's been going for around five days and I've just estimated that it will take another 15 to 30 days to complete which is a lot longer than I would like and drastically longer than if I were copying one 6 TB file.

In hindsight I should have read: [Speed up copying 1000000 small files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124527/speed-up-copying-1000000-small-files) but I didn't think of this before starting mv and I didn't anticipate that mv could take nearly a month to complete.

I think what's happening is the source hard drive is doing too much seeking because mv does not order by location on the disk.

I previously used mv with the same source and destination hard drives for two TB of large files and that completed quickly so I don't think the hard drives are at fault.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Increase the mq-deadline read_expire and write_expire settings.
2. Switch to the bfq scheduler.
   2A. Disable the low latency option.
   2B. Increase the backwards seek penalty.
3. Increase /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio
4. Increase /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs and /proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs
5. Decrease /proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure

None of these caused a drastic improvement. The theory was that more reads and writes would get scheduled allowing the scheduler to order them by sector reducing seeking. I also liked that bfq had a backward seek penalty which at the surface seems logical.

Are there any options to reduce the time-frame of the existing mv process or would it be worth it to stop the mv process and use something else or do I need to wait it out since I have already let it run for so long and knowing that if I stop mv I will have a tough time picking back up because it left all the files in the source directories.