# Is there a faster way to copy from terminal on macOS?

Tags: rsync, cp, macos

I just copied 1TB of files, zillions of them, from one external USB disk to another and it took 2 days over 5GBPS USB.

I have used rsync.

rsync seems to me to be serial, I mean, one file at a time.

I have confirmed that by looking at the traffic on the disk tab of activity monitor and the activity there was relatively low.

Is there some terminal app or some trick I can use to copy multiple files at a time and speed the process?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from starting several `rsync` processes, as long as you ensure they don't try to copy overlapping sets of files. However, they would still use the same _singular_ data bus, so speedup would definitely not be linear.

Comment: Do you happen to be using rsync's compress option? If so, try running without it. In my experience it slows down the transfer process tremendously.

Comment: You need to find the actual bottleneck of the copy. You made sure, it's not disk performance, but is it USB bandwidth (overhead for extremely large number of small files?) or CPU performance (unlikely, but maybe you have some virus scanner checking each file before proceeding) or what else? Maybe it's worth to test with only some small part of the data and compare `rsync` with `cp -R`.

Comment: External USB drives can be very slow. Typically they have a cache which makes them appear fast for the first 100MB or so, but their sustained write speed will disappoint. The 5Gb/s is the bus speed. All that this tells you is that you are not limited by the bus bandwidth. With over 1TB in 48 hours you are getting about 10MB/s which is not unreasonable. Top of the range drives can get 10 times faster random write performance, bottom of the range can be 10 times slower. Does the external drive call itself and "SSD"?

Comment: not SSD. The external disks are, unfortunately, HDD.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124583/194382

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
ps -ef | grep 'rsync' | grep -v 'grep'
```

you should see something like this:

```
root        7520    7514 12 20:50 pts/0    00:05:46 rsync --checksum --one-file-system --recursive --outbuf=Line --links --perms --times --group --owner --devices --specials --verbose --out-format=%t|%i|%M|%b|%f| --delete-delay --whole-file --human-readable --protect-args --ignore-errors --msgs2stderr ./ /DB001_F7/
root        7514    7512  0 20:50 pts/0    00:00:25 rsync --checksum --one-file-system --recursive --outbuf=Line --links --perms --times --group --owner --devices --specials --verbose --out-format=%t|%i|%M|%b|%f| --delete-delay --whole-file --human-readable --protect-args --ignore-errors --msgs2stderr ./ /DB001_F7/
root        7512       1 17 20:50 pts/0    00:08:27 rsync --checksum --one-file-system --recursive --outbuf=Line --links --perms --times --group --owner --devices --specials --verbose --out-format=%t|%i|%M|%b|%f| --delete-delay --whole-file --human-readable --protect-args --ignore-errors --msgs2stderr ./ /DB001_F7/"
```

In other words, [rsync](/questions/tagged/rsync) had 3 processes running in parallel for file copying, maybe more if you have more than 4 CPUs (what I have in my core).

As Kefka said, compression option maybe forced the serialization of backup data into a single data stream, and that too would slow things down, on top of the CPU utilization for the compression.

For **time consumption**, there are a few modes that change the behaviour.  Specifically, if you are using **--checksum** for every backup, backup times take up to 2.5 hours for a 250 GB partition, vs 15-20 minutes on what I call updates (cumulative delta from last full backup).  Doing a full image copy (empty destination directory; copy everything) without --checksum would take about 1-1.5 hours, just because of the sheer volume of data.

My own backup device is via [usb](/questions/tagged/usb) as well, a WD 4TB MyBook.  I had to tweak the [grub](/questions/tagged/grub) because of my physical configuration.  Your own hardware configuration may need tweeking as well if the USB is slower than expected.  This is what I have:

```
# quirk specification is to suppress UAS for external USB3 drive operating on USB2 channel.
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1 usb-storage.quirks=1058:25ee:u ipv6.disable=1"
```

If you are unsure of the performance hit using your USB drive, you can try, firstly a tar command of an ISO image from internal hard disk to another location on your internal hard disk, then tar that same ISO to a location on your USB drive to see if there is much difference in speed.  Use the date command before and after to get a sense of the time usage for both scenarios.  Then try doing rsync for that same ISO image, using your normal options, and see if there is much difference in time for completing that transfer to your USB.

I would try that rsync with the single ISO for a few different option for your rsync until you find what works best for you, balancing integrity of data at destination, with job duration for backups with rsync.  Only once that best combination is found should you move on to directory, disk or system backups, at which point you have assurance that your transfer were completed as expected.

Comment: thanks!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Duck, just a quick comment.  if this answer provides what you needed to know, I would encourage you to click on the checkmark next to the question to indicate that it is the answer that addresses the needs in your question.  That way, other users will know to give it a closer review for their own needs.